# Django: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'first_name'

Tags: django, django-forms

I am writing a class-based view that lets the employees setup their profile.  Because the employee model has a few foreign key field (e.g. employer is a forieng key referencing company model), I decided not to use ModelForm and resort to good old forms so the user can enter the name of the company they work in rather than 32.

Here is my code:

```
class Employee_ProfileSetting(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label = 'First Name', max_length = 30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label = 'Last Name', max_length = 30)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    employer = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
    cell = forms.CharField(max_length = 20)
    driver_license_num = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    birth_year = forms.IntegerField()
    start_date = forms.IntegerField(help_text = 'Year you started with the company')
    title = forms.CharField(max_length = 30)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if not args: # args is empty, meaning a fresh object            
            super(Employee_ProfileSetting, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        else:
            # Retrieving the form's information
            self.first_name = args[0].get('first_name')
            self.last_name = args[0]['last_name']
            self.email = args[0]['email']
            self.cell = args[0]['cell']
            self.driver_license_num = args[0]['driver_license_num']
            self.birth_year = args[0]['birth_year']
            self.start_year = args[0]['start_date']
            self.title = args[0]['title']

            super(Employee_ProfileSetting, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The constructor would then allow me to do this in my class-based view:

```
# Inside class AdminSetting(View):  
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        employee_profile = Employee_ProfileSetting(**cd) # Calling the constructor
        employee_profile.save()  # The save function is overridden


        admin, created = Employee.objects.get_or_create(**cd)  # If a matching employee exists, it gets that object.  Otherwise, it creates it.

        if created:  # Object was not found, and so it was created
            return HttpResponseRedirect('success.html')
```

When I run it, it gives me the error:

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'first_name'

So, my problem is two-fold:

1) What is wrong with the code? and what does that error mean?

2) Is there a better way to let the user fill in all the fields, including the foreign key fields, in a form and save fields accordingly? e.g. the field corresponding to a foreign key is saved in its respective table first (company1.employee_set.create() and then saving the other fields.  Can a ModelForm be used?

Comment: Please show your `Employee` model, show full `AdminSetting` view and form that you provided in form_class of that view. Also show your 'save' method from `Employee_ProfileSetting` form.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor of model can't take any arguments that have no matching field inside model. So if you try to pass `first_name` into model that doesn't have `first_name` field, you will get that exception.

To do it properly, you can create multiple forms and use them. Form should ignore extra `POST` data and take only what it needs. Also you can pass `commit=False` into `ModelForm.save` method, so created object won't be saved. That way you can pass some additional data, for example `Employee_ProfileSettings` ID can be passed into `Employee` before saving it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I am not using a model neither a ModelForm, I am using a form.  If you can think of a way to use ModelForm to accomplish what I am after, please do expand on it a bit.  The __init__ method should only initialize the form so I can later on use {% for field in form %} {{field}} in the template.  On your note on using mutiple forms and using them, can you elaborate how to do that?

Comment: I just realized that you're using class-based views. Why are you not using FormView default implementation with overwriting `is_valid`? Also, why are you calling form constructor in form_valid? If you're doing it, you propably should init it with post data, like normal form. And if `Employee_ProfileSetting` is normal form, not model form, why are you calling it's save method? There are too many questions about your code right now to post full answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way you define the init is very strange. It should be something like this:

```
def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):

    if not data: # data is empty, meaning a fresh object            
        super(Employee_ProfileSetting, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    else:
        # Retrieving the form's information
        self.first_name = data[0].get('first_name')
        self.last_name = data[0]['last_name']
        self.email = data[0]['email']
        self.cell = data[0]['cell']
        self.driver_license_num = data[0]['driver_license_num']
        self.birth_year = data[0]['birth_year']
        self.start_year = data[0]['start_date']
        self.title = data[0]['title']

        super(Employee_ProfileSetting, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And second thing is how you call you class:

```
employee_profile = Employee_ProfileSetting(**cd)
```

Which expands all the clean_data list. This expands to:

```
employee_profile = Employee_ProfileSetting(first_name=cleaned_data[first_name], ...)
```

Instead you should call it like this:

```
employee_profile = Employee_ProfileSetting(form.cleaned_data)
```

So that the dictionary instance is not expanded.

Finally, I don't think I understood why you cannot use a model form...

Comment: Well, you cannot use a ModelForm because given that the form includes a foreign key referencing Company model and given that initially you do not have any data in the company model, the ModelForm will display a select widget with no option to select.  So, I thought why not make a form with bunch of fields, receive those data, and save them to their respective models by customizing the save function.

Comment: One solution would be to have a ModelForm, and exclude the Company field, like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use

You can then add a new field to enter the company as text (company_text), adding a validate_company_text, and override the init and save method to fill the real company field.